# html - how to remove right margin completely?

Tags: html, css

I want the dark rectangle in the picture below to be completely fit within the window;

I set `margin-left:-8px;` to remove the left margin completely; but what about the right margin?(changing `margin-right` doesn't have that effect) how can I remove that too so that the dark rectangle touches the border?

my code:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <span style="margin-left:-8px; display:inline-block; width:100%; background:#2F4F4F";><font face="Georgia" size="3" color="#FFFFFF">hello world!</font></span>
    </body>
    </head>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: If you want a full width block, i suggest using a `<div>` instead of a `<span>`, which is semantically more correct. also, please avoid inline styles and styling tags - [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: try following link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352962/a-weird-spacing-appears-when-i-use-margin-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to remove the padding/margin on the html/body elements:

```css
body, html { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Comment: excellent; thanks; but what if I want your settings to be applied just for the dark rectangle an other elements have their default margin?

Comment: You are only removing the default margin on the body/html elements, not the default margin on other elements.  If you really want all other elements to have a default left/right margin, you need to add that explictly to them - or, you could set the left/right margin on the body to be, say 10px and then apply a negative left/right margin of -10px on the dark rectangle.

Comment: if you want to keep the default margin then width:calc(100% + 16px) is a solution http://jsfiddle.net/PgYw5/

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

?

Answer (score 3):

The body element has a margin of 8px by default. Remove it.

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: @Max - yes you're right - 8px - I edited this, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try following code

```css
span{
   display:inline-block; width:100%; background:#2F4F4F;margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html,body{
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<span><font face="Georgia" size="3" color="#FFFFFF">hello world!</font></span>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfqe6/)

Comment: excellent; thanks; but what if I want your settings to be applied just for the dark rectangle an other elements have their default margin?

Comment: @wiki No, That will remove margin from whole page!