# A weird spacing appears when I use margin property

Tags: html, css, margin

My HTML and CSS as follow:

```css
    div {
          background: yellow;
          width: 77px;
          height: 77px;
          border: 1px dotted red
          }

        #one {
          margin: 0px 21px 41px 41px
          }
```

```html
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>LOL</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div id="one"></div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

My margin-top value is 0px, nevertheless, a spacing between my square and the top of the page appears.

Why?`<br>`
Here is an illustration :

[image]

And `JSFiddle` : http://jsfiddle.net/9vQZ9/1/

Comment: Hey, I see that you got an answer already. However, I would like to show you this... http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ You place it before your css, that way your site is more cross-browser friendly when it comes to css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this:-

```
html,body{ margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is browser's body default CSS which is margin:8px; To rewrite that, use this CSS as well:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/9vQZ9/2/)
*CSS*

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[image: Check it in FireBug]

Many designers even use, to reset padding and margins of all elements, if any

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Why does it work with body selector, and not with div? It's weird, body tag overrides div tag

Comment: @user3546093 Depends on the browser. Some have just padding, some just margin for the body. Even `ul` have default margin's. [Check this fiddle in firebug](http://jsfiddle.net/4vx45/).. So it is better to use `*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} `