# Margin-right not being removed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a margin-right being added to the page which especially noticable on mobile devices. I have tried everything in this [question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059929/html-how-to-remove-right-margin-completely?lq=1) such as `body, html {margin:0;}` but nothing is working. I've tried adding !important to it aswell as `margin-right:-8px;` but I'm still seeing a default margin on the right.

[image]

EDIT:
I've narrowed it down to the 2 divs that are causing the problem and put them in a codepen. http://codepen.io/caesar9/pen/jWyaoq

Comment: A live example might be useful.

Comment: !important is added to force the margins of bootstrap

Comment: Use your browser's inspector to see where the margin is coming from.

Comment: it's probably one of your elements inside `body` that has a right margin. post some code for someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.help-1 img {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The image was the problem - its because `100% + margin = more than 100%`
If you want margin then add padding on it's container instead

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the selected element has `margin:0!important` and `padding:0!important`.
Else, check if the `width` is set correctly. Otherwise, give us your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it!

The IMG in the first div was overflowing for some reason with `width: 100%;` so I reduced it to 90%.

I hadn't set a width on the footer so I added `width: 100%;` to that as well and the margins now gone.

Why would the IMG overflow the element with `width: 100%;`? & why would the footer overflow if it didn't have a width set?